# Creating 2dIndex for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Using MongoDb and Pymongo I've been trying to create a 2d index of my locations field in my database. I followed guides on how to make the geoJSON object creating entries to the DB collection "Locations". The reason for this is so I can do a "near" search of entries into my DB and return a list of locations, kind of like how you'd search for cafe's on google and a load of  markers would appear within that area.

my DB entries look like the following:

```
new_location = {
            "name": <name>,
            "description": <descript>,
            "rating": <rating>,
            "location": {"type": "FeatureCollection", "features" :[ {
                "type" : "Feature","geometry" :{
                    "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [lng, lat]}, "properties" : ""}]},
            "file": <file>,
            "posted_by": session["user"]
        }
        mongo.db.locations.insert_one(new_location)
```

Then tried to index this "location" object the Db with the following

```
 mongo.db.locations.create_index([("location", GEO2D)])
```

No matter what I do I keep getting errors about my array not being in the correct format

> > pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Index build failed: 890e39f7-f09a-45e9-beed-1b879be03285: Collection 60870b6f802c945b786e98a9_wildCamping.locations ( 02746b9f-e586-488e-9d24-ce9c882cf539 ) :: caused by :: location object expected, location array not in correct format, full error: {'operationTime': Timestamp(1620766990, 9), 'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'Index build failed: 890e39f7-f09a-45e9-beed-1b879be03285: Collection 60870b6f802c945b786e98a9_wildCamping.locations ( 02746b9f-e586-488e-9d24-ce9c882cf539 ) :: caused by :: location object expected, location array not in correct format', 'code': 16804, 'codeName': 'Location16804', '$clusterTime': {'clusterTime': Timestamp(1620766990, 9), 'signature': {'hash': b"C\xc3/\x1bo!I.\xec\x18z6i'\xc4\xa6)\xe9\x86\xff", 'keyId': 6950140143088959491}}}

I'm gone bleary-eyed at this stage trying to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: cannot index, if it's nested this way. I recommend you to create a separate collection of "feature", where it has it's own geometry

Answer (score 1):

Ye i'd tried to create a GeoJSON object that fitted the required format mentioned in the GeoJSON Objects documentation but it just wouldn't work. I eventually went down route of creating a 2dsphere index of legacy coordinates.

```
 mongo.db.locations.create_index([("locations.location", "2dsphere")])

    c = mongo.db.locations.find({ "locations.location" :
                         {"$near" :
                           {"$geometry" :
                              { "type" : "Point" ,
                                "coordinates" : [ -6.86 , 52.2 ] } ,
                             "$maxDistance ": 100000 }}})
```

also the structure of my collection insert changed back to my original simpler (legacy coordinate) form.

```
            "name": request.form.get("location_name"),
            "description": request.form.get("location_description"),
            "rating": request.form.get("rating"),
            "location": [lng, lat],
            "file": request.form.get("file"),
            "posted_by": session["user"]
        }
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

`Feature` and `FeatureCollection` are not in the MongoDB list of supported [GeoJSON Objects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/geojson/).